# Subíndice fuera de intervalo VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

Estimadxs, buen día, tengo un dilema que no termino de cerrar. Estoy cargando Un `MSHFlexGrid` en `VB6` con `StoredProcedure` hecho en `SQLServer`, hasta ahí va todo bien
El problema es que a la hora de cargarlo, es como que entra en un `LOOP` interminable y sale el cartel de índice fuera de intervalo. Adjunto el código así alguien me dice a dónde le estoy pifiando en mi código:

```
Option Explicit
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim IntRecord As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    LblApeNom.Caption = FrmModSolNuevo.LblApellido.Caption & ", " & FrmModSolNuevo.LblNombre.Caption
    LblTitulo.Caption = FrmModSolNuevo.LblTitulo.Caption
    '..................................
    SP_GrillaEndosos
End Sub


Private Sub Grilla()
    Dim I As Integer
    
    FlexEndosos.Cols = 11
    FlexEndosos.Rows = IntRecord + 2
    FlexEndosos.MergeCells = flexMergeFree
    FlexEndosos.FixedRows = 2
    '--------------------------1ºFILA - MERGEFREE-------------
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 0) = ""
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 1) = "CÓDIGO PLANES"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "CÓDIGO PLANES"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 3) = "PLAN ENDOSO"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 4) = "PLAN ENDOSO"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 5) = "CUOTAS GENERADAS"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 6) = "CUOTAS GENERADAS"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 7) = "CUOTAS GENERADAS"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 8) = "ENDOSO"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 9) = "ENDOSO"
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(0, 10) = "ENDOSO"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(0) = 800
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(0) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 0) = "ENDOSO"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(1) = 1000
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(1) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 1) = "ORIGEN"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(2) = 1000
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(2) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 2) = "DESTINO"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(3) = 1200
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(3) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 3) = "V.NOMINAL"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(4) = 1100
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(4) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 4) = "$ CUOTA"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(5) = 1000
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(5) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 5) = "CANTIDAD"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(6) = 1000
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(6) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 6) = "DESDE Nº"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(7) = 1000
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(7) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 7) = "HASTA Nº"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(8) = 2400
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(8) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 8) = "TIPO"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(9) = 1200
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(9) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 9) = "FECHA"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.ColWidth(10) = 1200
    FlexEndosos.ColAlignment(10) = 4
    FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(1, 10) = "USUARIO"
    '------------------------------------------------------
    FlexEndosos.MergeRow(0) = True
    FlexEndosos.MergeCol(10) = True
    
    '------------------------CENTRO LAS COLUMNAS FIJAS---------------------
    For I = 0 To FlexEndosos.Cols - 1
      FlexEndosos.FixedAlignment(I) = 4
    Next I
End Sub

Private Sub CargarGrillaEndosos()
    Dim I As Integer
    
    I = 1
    RS.MoveFirst
    IntRecord = RS!Rs_Count
    Do While RS.EOF = False
        I = I + 1
        If RS!Tipo = "A" Then
            FlexEndosos.Rows = RS!Rs_Count + 3
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 0) = RS!Endoso
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 1) = RS!PlanOrigen
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 2) = RS!PlanDestino
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 3) = Format(RS!ValorNominal, "##,##")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 4) = Format(RS!ImporteComprobante, "##,##0.00")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 5) = 0
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 6) = 0
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 7) = 0
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 8) = RS!Modulo
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 9) = Format$(RS!FechaHecho, "dd/MM/yyyy")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 10) = RS!Usuario
        Else
            FlexEndosos.Rows = RS!Rs_Count + 3
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 0) = RS!PlanOrigen
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 1) = RS!PlanOrigen
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 2) = RS!PlanDestino
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 3) = Format(RS!ValorNominal, "##,##")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 4) = Format(RS!ImporteComprobante, "##,##0.00")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 5) = RS!cantidad
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 6) = RS!CuotaImpresaMin
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 7) = RS!CuotaImpresaMax
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 8) = RS!Modulo
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 9) = Format$(RS!FechaHecho, "dd/MM/yyyy")
            FlexEndosos.TextMatrix(I, 10) = RS!Usuario
        End If
        'RS.Close
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop
    'FlexEndosos.Rows = FlexEndosos.Rows - 1
End Sub

Private Sub SP_GrillaEndosos()
    Dim CmdSQL As ADODB.Command
    Set CmdSQL = New ADODB.Command
    CmdSQL.ActiveConnection = Cn
    CmdSQL.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    
    ActivarRS
    
    CmdSQL.CommandText = "SP_GrillaEndosos"
    CmdSQL.Parameters("@titulo") = CLng(LblTitulo.Caption)
    Set RS = CmdSQL.Execute
    Set CmdSQL = Nothing
    
    
    CargarGrillaEndosos
    
    Grilla
End Sub

Private Sub ActivarRS()
    Set RS = New Recordset
    RS.CursorLocation = adUseServer
End Sub

Private Sub CmdSalir_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

El Stored devuelve un select de una tabla temporal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en Private Sub SP_GrillaEndosos() posiciono

```
CargarGrillaEndosos
Grilla
```

Esto solo me carga el valor de la primer columna (de 0 a 7 - lo cual son datos correcto), al debugear me doy cuenta de que si trae datos pero luego borra todo por hacer el diseño luego de cargar los items.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en Private Sub SP_GrillaEndosos() posiciono

```
Grilla
CargarGrillaEndosos
```

MoveFirst, trae el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gif de lo que sucede:

[LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1750OIik5wnWKtUQl61rnyTeRkJcyGMV2/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Cuando hablaba de invertir el codigo no me referia a eso.. si no a no cerrar ninguna conexion hasta que tengas efectivamente los datos...

Comment: Pues, como ves no he cerrado las conexiones @gbianchi

Comment: ok.. entonces tiene algo que ver con el diseño.. no estas guardando los datos en las columnas que pensas.. Dijiste que si no pones los headers se ve todo bien?? entonces por ahi tenemos que atacar, pero ya ahi se me acaban las ideas porque nunca trabaje asi... al unir columnas, fijate en cual de todas lo estas mostrando..

Comment: Vos sabes que no se que pasa jajajjaa me puse con el debug y me ocurre lo siguiente, paso el puntero del mouse una vez y muestra el dato (todo esto con el punto de interrupción puesto) no hago absolutamente nada más que mover el puntero del mouse. Como decía, acerco el puntero del mouse una vez y muestra el dato. Quito el puntero del mouse y vuelvo a acercarlo y el dato pasa a estar en nulo jajjaa @gbianchi te dejo un gif para que veas lo que me pasa

Comment: Alguna otra cosa esta borrando la tabla temporal??? rarooooooooooo